# How to deploy and run ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

This is what I did:

1. I created a default ASP.NET Web API with the only Values controller. No modification.
2. I installed all the plugins, libs which you can imagine
3. I got 503 Service Unavailable
4. I updated Windows 12R2 with the latest updates and after that I got 500.19 "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."
   Instead of 503
5. I modified Configure method in the startup.cs:

   ```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment 
    env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && 
             !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            });
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
   ```

It did not help

6. I changed the properties of the project, changing IISExpress profile to IIS, played with the different settings for x64, x86 in the deployment settings - nothing helped.
7. I added  `[AspNetCoreHostingModel]InProcess[/AspNetCoreHostingModel]` into the project file
   and  updated deployed web.config where I replaced:

   [aspNetCore processPath=".\TempTest5.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"/]

with:

```
  [aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TempTest5.dll"  
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="InProcess" /]
```

And nothing helped!

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: I also installed .NET Core runtime, .NET CORE SDK (Yes, yes),  .NET Core Hosting Bundle, and yes, I updated the IIS Pool, setting it to No managed. I also followed the bunch of youtube and guru's tutorials and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run/install

**Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle**

//StartQuote//
Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS server. The bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module allows ASP.NET Core apps to run behind IIS.
//EndQuote//

(from)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Check your app pool.  Here is what I have. (Below image)

[image]

Here is my web.config (for my (like yours) simple (almost default) app).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\My.WebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

windowsAuthentication is probably "optional"..aka, you can probably have it as false.

Comment: Yes I did and I also updated the IIS Pool setting it to no managed

Comment: Hmm.  I just verified my app pool settings against what you said (and updated my answer)....so that looks right.  I added my web.config to try a sanity check against.

Comment: And your example does not work neither. Moreover, I downloaded the example from https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22  and it does not work...